# foreach xml from specific results in tags

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I'm currently using the following code

```
foreach ($xml->sport[0]->event[1] as $gameinfo):
```

Which loads Eng. Premier League. Is there a way I can draw the data from an  where the id=3 rather than using the [1] method?

The XML is:

```
<sports file_date="2012-11-16T14:30:27.853">
<sport name="Football" id="1">
    <event name="World Cup" id="1"></event>
    <event name="Eng. Premier League" id="3"></event>
    <event name="French Ligue 1" id="4"></event>
<sport>
```

Comment: Did you try accessing `attributes()` where `id = 3` ?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with XML, how would I do that in the foreach statement?

Comment: full dom/xpath? `//event[@id=3]`?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<?php

$string = '<sports file_date="2012-11-16T14:30:27.853">
<sport name="Football" id="1">
    <event name="World Cup" id="1"></event>
    <event name="Eng. Premier League" id="3"></event>
    <event name="French Ligue 1" id="4"></event>
</sport>
</sports>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $string );

foreach( $xml->sport->children() as $gameinfo )
{
    if( $gameinfo->attributes()->id == 3 )
    {
        // do your thing
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Here's my code, but it's generating no results?

http://jsfiddle.net/krischambers/KWwTZ/

Comment: And turn on error reporting, I got this using your code: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 7` and a logical `Fatal error: Call to a member function event() on a non-object in test.php on line 7`